# MySQL Workbench

Tags: package-management, 19.04, mysql-workbench

Just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04. MySQL Workbench has been deleted. Will it come back in the near future?
The mysql-workbench-community_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.10_amd64.deb can't install!
Do I need to compile it from source to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Package not available at mysql downloads page for 19.04 yet. There are packages for 18.04 and 18.10.
You have to wait when it will be released or build from source
Download source code [there](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (select Source in dropdown and choose from list Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive) and follow build/install instructions [there](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/INSTALL)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't compile/link these modules! The CMakeError-log file contains:
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba91b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
Linking C executable cmTC_ba91b
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba91b.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba91b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_ba91b -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba91b.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_ba91b] Error 1